# Blazor - why does two way binding work for List but not String in custom component?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

All documentation regarding using two way binding claims that in order to have two way binding in a custom component you need to use an EventCallback. And yet when using a List it works automatically. I would like to know why?

Example Page index.razor:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt ListOfValues="@ListOfValues" StringValue="@StringValue" />

<div @onclick="WriteValues">then click me</div>


@code {
    List<string> ListOfValues { get; set; } = new();
    public string StringValue { get; set; } = "";
    private void WriteValues()
    {
        foreach(var v in ListOfValues){
            Console.WriteLine($"ListOfValues: {v}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"StringValue: {StringValue}");
    }
}
```

Example component SurveyPrompt.razor:

```
<div class="alert alert-secondary mt-4">
   
    <div @onclick="bubu">click me</div>
   
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public List<string> ListOfValues { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public string StringValue { get; set; } = "";

    private void bubu()
    {
        ListOfValues.Add("First Value set in a component");
        ListOfValues.Add("Second Value set in a component");
        
        StringValue = "A Value set in a component";
    }
}
```

When running the app and clicking on "click me" and then clicking on "then click me" The console will show that the `ListOfValues` variable has values in index.razor that were filled in SurveyPrompt.razor but `StringValue` remains empty

How page looks:

[image]

How console looks after clicking on "click me" and then on "then click me":

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of `List<T>`, it is not an effect of binding that you observe.  What happens is that in your `index.razor` page you create a list (ListOfValues) which you then pass to your `SurveyPrompt`.  Note that you do not copy the list, you pass it by reference.  Both `index.razor` and `SurveyPrompt` "share" the same list instance. Therefore, when you make changes to the list, they are visible by everything that keeps a reference to it.

Strings, though, are immutable.  When you change the string, you do not modify the original string, but create a new one in memory that replaces the old one. As a result, after the modificaton, `index.razor` and `SurveyPrompt` have two separate strings.